# Shell code: access violation exception for no obvious reason

Tags: c, assembly

In VS2012 I wrote:

```
int main(){
    char *myshell = 
    "\x50"  // push eax
    "\x58"  // pop eax
    "\xC3"; //ret

    __asm call myshell

    return 0;
}
```

I followed the debugger line by line, and when the CPU attempts to execute "push eax", or anything else I decide to change it to for that matter, it fires a failing exception, saying:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00265858 in ConsoleApplication8.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00265858.
```

Why is that?

Comment: I think this is a DEP issue.

Comment: The segment the array is in is not marked as executable.

Comment: I looked up wikipedia for DEP, and that almost certainly is the issue. Does this not seem to slam the door almost completely in attackers' faces who exploit overflow issues?

Comment: Is /NXCOMPAT linker option disabled?

Comment: @kalkanistovinko, That's exactly the point of DEP. To prevent such attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Google points here.

You can use [VirtualProtect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/windows/desktop/aa366898(v=vs.85).aspx) before calling.

```
DWORD oldProtection = 0;
VirtualProtect((void*)myshell, 3, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtection);
```